# install error of CASAVA on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, gzip, bioinformatics, bzip2

I am trying to install CASAVA Bcl2Fastq 1.8.3 (developed for CentOS) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. However, I got an error message "No support for gzip compression" and the install failed. Luckily, I found a solution for this problem:

```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread* /usr/lib
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib
```

But now I got another similar error "No support for bzip2 compression". I am wondering if I can do something similar to solve this error?

Comment: Have you got the bzip and gzip libraries installed on your system? Can you post the actual error output from gcc?

Comment: @niallhaslam, I am sure those libraries were installed. Finally I solved this problem by linking the bzip2 library file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ to /usr/lib (as below). But I still cannot figure out the cause. Unfortunately, I don't have the error message now, but it really didn't provide any more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved this by linking the bzip2 library file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ to /usr/lib:

```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2* /usr/lib
```

But I am wondering why gcc cannot find the library files automatically, is it a problem of my Unbuntu installation or some incompatibility of the CASAVA Bcl2Fastq 1.8.3 software (because it was developed and tested on CentOS)?

Answer (score 3):

For those returning to this issue - if you can't find any of the appropriate libbz2* files under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, try:

> sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev libbz2